# Android - using attribute color in selector

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles

I need to apply a custom color attribute (that I named ?attr/customTintPrimary) to some views, according to a enabled/disabled state.

So I created this color selector, named primary_if_enabled :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="?attr/customTintPrimary"  android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

On a TextView's textColor, this attribute in a selector works perfectly:

```
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_if_enabled"
```

However it doesn't work for the two other views. For instance I try to apply it as a tint color to a drawable:

```
                        android:tint="@color/primary_if_enabled"
```

Instead of primaryColor, a red color is applied.

I made two more tests to localize the issue: if I pass directly the attribute (as tint) to the drawable (like this : `android:tint="?attr/customTintPrimary"`), then it works (albeit without the state check). Also, If I use directly a @color/ (instead of ?attr/customTintPrimary) in the selector (primary_if_enabled), it also works (albeit with a static color). But the combination of both, that works for the TextView, doesn't work for the drawable. Why is that ?

I'm trying to make sense of this, and where the problem exactly is:

- attr + selector (in textview): works
- attr + drawable (1st test): works
- selector + drawable (2nd test): works
- attr + selector + drawable: doesn't work

Is there a reason why? How can I make this work?

I saw there was a limitation pre-lollipop, however I'm targetting and testing on a 5.1, so it should be working.

Any hint or idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can programmatically create the selector and set the tint. However, this would just be a workaround.

Comment: @NatarajKR, thanks for the hint ! Ideally I'd like to do it straightaway and cleanly, as I feel it should work... But if it doesn't I guess I'll have to change things programmatically (either the selector like you said, or directly change the tint).